# datatable with some custom search fields

Tags: php, forms, search, datatable

First time I have implemented the datatable plugin, and obviously by the help of stackoverflow's member. Thanks them again. Now my concern issue is like the following:
   I have a page with some search fields like name text field, username text field, category dropdown, age range etc. and one submit button to search. By default all the records will be showing and by making use of datatable, I am able to sort them either ascending order or descending order. I remove the default search field of the plugin by css only(display:none). Now when I search records through that search form, my list of records should implement with that datatable plugin. But I am unable to do that. Please help me how to process.
The custom search is like:

```
<form name="search_user_form" id="search_user_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET" > 


    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" class="form_table" id="searching_parameter" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name : <input type="text" class="textbox_small" name="search_name" id="search_name" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['search_name']; ?>" /></td>
                            <td>Username : <input type="text" class="textbox_small" name="search_username" id="search_username" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['search_username']; ?>" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email : <input type="text" class="textbox_small" name="search_email" id="search_email" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['search_email']; ?>" /></td>
                            <td>Age &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;: <!--<input type="text" class="textbox_small" name="search_age" id="search_age" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['search_age']; ?>" />-->

                           <input type="text" size="3" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['min_age']; ?>" name="min_age" id="min_age" maxlength="2" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" > &nbsp;&nbsp;
                           To  &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" size="3" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['max_age']; ?>" name="max_age" id="max_age" maxlength="2" onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" >                        

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">Privilege:
                       <select class="soring_select" name="search_privilege" id="search_privilege" style="height:28px;">
                            <option value="0" <?php echo $selection_agent;?>>Agent</option>
                            <option value="1" <?php echo $selected_admin;?>>Admin</option>
                            <option value="2" <?php echo $selected_supeadmin;?>>Superadmin</option>
                            <option value="3" <?php echo $selected_owner;?>>Owner</option>
                            <option value="all" <?php echo $selected_no;?>>All Privilege</option>
                        </select>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="search_user_btn" id="search_user_btn" value="Search">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Cancel" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

and for plugin:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                            "bProcessing": true,
                            "bServerSide": true,
                        "sAjaxSource": "datatabledb.php?query=<?php (isset($_REQUEST['search_user_btn']))?$search_sql:'';?>",
                            "bJQueryUI": true,
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                            "oTableTools": {
                                "aButtons": [

                                    {
                                        "sExtends": "csv",
                                        "sButtonText": "Save to CSV"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }       

                        } );
```

Comment: Can you show us the code so that we can help you?

Comment: sure please check the above post again

Answer (score 0):

You can start with datatables MultiFilter But you should pass the data in Key/value pairs after pressing submit buttons:

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnMultiFilter

you can call this by following:

```
var defaultFilter = {"name":"john","username":"userjohn"};
oTable.fnMultiFilter(defaultFilter);
```

And for ranges you should do some stuff to make the change in API.